# Gulp throws errors after a while, and works again on reboot

Tags: node.js, gulp, phpspec

I've just started using Gulp, and am having an intermittent issue, where sometimes I'll get the following error, which occurs with no change in configuration, and only goes away if I reboot, I've removed `node_modules`, and `/tmp`, and it hasn't made any difference, I'm running Ubuntu 14.10:

```
$ gulp test
[21:31:52] Using gulpfile ~/work/kata/gulpfile.js
[21:31:52] Starting 'test'...
[21:31:52] Finished 'test' after 8.92 ms

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
```

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var phpspec = require('gulp-phpspec');
var run = require('gulp-run');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
//require('epipebomb')();

gulp.task('test', function() {
   gulp.src('spec/**/*.php')
       .pipe(run('clear'))
       .pipe(phpspec('', {notify: true, verbose: 'vvv' }))
       .on('error', notify.onError({
            title: 'PHPspec Tests:',
            message: 'Failed'
       }))
       .pipe(notify({ title: 'PHPspec Tests:', message: 'Passed' }));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['spec/**/*.php', 'app/*.php', 'app/**/*.php'], ['test']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['test', 'watch']);
```

**Update:**

This morning Gulp was working again, without a reboot, and has since stopped working again, all without any change to the configuration.

Comment: is it possible your pipe bomb is breaking your pipe? :^)

Comment: [epipebomb](https://github.com/mhart/epipebomb) was a suggestion I got on the Gulp IRC channel, it didn't help, so it's commented out.

Comment: It was a joke. I was not being serious. I was suggesting that you were having a pipe error whilst having a pipe bomb in your code, similar to how a pipe might be disagree with a pipe bomb IRL. :-)

Comment: I got that ;-) Should have added some smileys or something, but just thought it worth explaining anyway :-)